# How to Parameterize Hyperbola

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to parametrize general hyperbola (shown below) using $x=t$, $y=1/t$.  I tried to factor it, but I didn't get to the correct answer.

The hyperbola:

[image: hyperbola]

The correct answer:

[image: answer]

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation can be factored as
$$
\left({x\over a}+{y\over b}\right)\left({x\over a}-{y\over b}\right)=1.
$$
Set then:
$$
{x\over a}+{y\over b}=t
\quad\text{and}\quad
{x\over a}-{y\over b}={1\over t}.
$$

Comment: I tried this but it didn't get me to the answer

Comment: @AdamHafchadi You must solve for $x$ and $y$, it isn't so hard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a valid parametrisation would be:

$$ x = a * cosh(t)$$
$$ y = b * sinh(t)$$
$$ t \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: I didn`t learn what cosh mean so I am pretty sure there is a simpler way but thanks!.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT1:
At first consider a hyperbola rotated by $45^{0}$.

Difference of squares being unity is the common criterion. Some are simpler than the others. One possibility is

$$ x/a=\frac12 (t+1/t), y/b =\frac12(t-1/t)$$

which is constructed on Pythagorean triplets. I.e.,take

$$ (t^2+u^2, t^2-u^2, 2tu ) $$

and then divide all by $2tu$ and set $ u=1.$

The following are from circular and hyperbolic trig.

$$ x/a=\sec(t), y/b =\tan(t))$$

$$ x/a=\cosh(t), y/b =\sinh(t))$$

Then we rotate it back by $45^0$ rotation matrix.